# How do I use Cloud Foundry to login to my AWS endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am new to cloudfoundry. I have seen the examples of how we connect the cloudfoundry with ibm bmluemix but is it possible to do same way to aws. Like what API endpoint do I need to provide or I am missing here the something?

e.g. for blumix you do:
cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net

Comment: Could you edit and add details? It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Instead of IBM bluemix i want to use AWS cloud provider for my infra. So how can I use it ?